# Making bigger and revert button to original size Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a project to make 2 buttons that containing value before and after test score.

The student is 50 and every student have 2 buttons that containing their previous and present test score in some subject.
the button is placed in 2  columns Before and After, sorted by highest score and resize them depending on their score.
So we don't know how to identify which was the pair of those buttons.

So I decide to make if that "id" of pairing button is same 
eg: id="Score1"  and id="Score1_a"

Progress now, I make the pairing button in "Before" and "After" Columns change their color to Red if we hover mouse on one of them.

But it's still not enough.. 
So I use script to make the buttons bigger when we hover on it, but I don't know how to Revert it back to original size. 
Can you guys help me?

This is my script:

```
 <script>
  function mouseover(obj) {
 var id2=obj.id+"_a";
document.getElementById(obj.id).style.background = "magenta";
document.getElementById(obj.id).style.width = "100px";
document.getElementById(obj.id).style.height = "100px";
document.getElementById(id2).style.background = "magenta";
    }
  function mouseout(obj) {
 var id2=obj.id+"_a";
document.getElementById(obj.id).style.background = "deepskyblue";
document.getElementById(id2).style.background = "deepskyblue";
document.getElementById(obj.id).style.offsetwidth;
document.getElementById(obj.id).style.offsetheight;
   }
</script>

  <button id="score1" style='width:70px; height:70px;'>70</button>
  <button id="score1_a" style='width:65px; height:65px;'>65</button>
   <button id="score2" style='width:25px; height:25px;'>25</button>
   <button id="score2_a" style='width:50px; height:50px;'>50</button>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is that you are trying to achieve but based on my understanding i am retaining its original dimensions on mouse out.  There are multiple ways we can achieve this in more efficient way but make your code working you you will need to track the original height width and also its pair for each button. So solution can be,

```js
function mouseover(obj, pairId) {
  
 var id2=pairId;

 document.getElementById(obj.id).style.background = "magenta";
 document.getElementById(obj.id).style.width = "100px";
 document.getElementById(obj.id).style.height = "100px";
 document.getElementById(id2).style.background = "magenta";
}
function mouseout(obj, pairId, actualDim) {

 var id2=pairId;

 document.getElementById(obj.id).style.background = "deepskyblue";
 document.getElementById(id2).style.background = "deepskyblue";
 document.getElementById(obj.id).style.width = actualDim.w;
 document.getElementById(obj.id).style.height = actualDim.h;
}
```

```html
 <button id="score1" style='width:70px; height:70px;' onmouseover="mouseover(this, 'score1_a')" onmouseout="mouseout(this, 'score1_a', {w:'70px', h:'70px'})">70</button>
  <button id="score1_a" style='width:65px; height:65px;' onmouseover="mouseover(this, 'score1')" onmouseout="mouseout(this, 'score1', {w:'65px', h:'65px'})">65</button>
  <button id="score2" style='width:25px; height:25px;' onmouseover="mouseover(this, 'score1')" onmouseout="mouseout(this, 'score1', {w:'25px', h:'25px'})">25</button>
  <button id="score2_a" style='width:50px; height:50px;' onmouseover="mouseover(this, 'score1')" onmouseout="mouseout(this, 'score1', {w:'50px', h:'50px'})">50</button>
```

Comment: It Worked It Worked, Thanks.  But i have another problem, I want make pairing button bigger and revert back at same time, can I get the original size the pair button just by their id?

Comment: Yes you can here we are sending the object {w:'50px', h:'50px'} which is original sizes which is used for  restoring the size back to original. Same way we can pass the size to make button bigger as per button needs through 'mouseover'.

Comment: Done i've do like your advice and it turns out great. thank you so much